How to view with Docker logs without sudo or root permissions on AstraLinux SE 1.7?
I am on AstraLinux SE 1.7.
Docker (docker run) is run as root user and accordingly in the folder /var/lib/docker/docker/containers/id_container rights holders are root.
Task: To be able to view the .log file without root permissions, even if you grant permissions via chmod, still after you stop the container and start it again - a new folder with logs is created in /var/lib/docker/docker/containers and you have to grant permissions again.
Question: Is there any way to make it so that when docker creates a folder in /logs, it creates it already with read/modify/run rights? Maybe it is possible to change this parameter somewhere in the configuration of Docker itself? Or there are alternative ways of solution
The main task is to make sure that when a Docker container is started, the logs of this container can be viewed by a normal user without root permissions.
